# Transmission-daemons settings file not saving. Watch doesn't work

Tags: raspberry-pi, transmission, json

I tried adding a watch folder to my transmission settings but I failed.

I'm working on a Raspberry Pi and edited the file in `/etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json` with the fields:

```
"watch-dir": "~/torrent-drop",
"watch-dir-enabled": true
```

That didn't work so I tried modding the field to `"/home/pi/torrents"` for the new *torrents* folder I created. Saved with ctrl-o in nano with sudo privileges and restarted the daemon using:

```
sudo service transmission-daemon stop
sudo service transmission-daemon start
```

When I look at the contents of `cat settings.json` the file got back to the original state (torrent-drop), even though I saved it with sudo using nano. Seems to get overwritten every time…

Looking at `cat /var/logs/syslog | grep watch` I get:

```
Using inotify to watch directory "~/torrent-drop" (watch.c:73)
Unable to watch "~/torrent-drop": No such file or directory (watch.c:79)
```

How can I make the new folder *torrents* apply to settings.json? Am I restarting the daemon incorrectly?

EDIT: just tried `sudo /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon stop` and start, doesn't work either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to stop the transmission-daemon before editing the settings.json file, because on every shutdown of the program it saves the settings. So shutting it down after editing the settings file will remove everything you edited.